# multiple text UIPickerviews use same array

Tags: swift, uipickerview

The below code works when populating one pickerview but I am trying to use the same array to control two pickerviews and let the user pick two different values. Note, the values could be the same or different. based on the setup of the code it set the same value to both textfields.

```
// Load FI Information

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

    return lenders[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    return lenders.count

}

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView == currentLenderPicker{
    orginalLender.text = lenders[row]


    }else if pickerView == newLenderPicker{
    newMortgageLender.text = lenders[row]

    }

    selectedLenderKey = lendersKey[row]

    if let selectedLender = currentLender.filter({ $0.fiName == lenders[row] }).first {
        Global.selectedRate = selectedLender
    }


    self.view.endEditing(false)
}
```

I made a few changes based on what I have learned from searching. But still not where I need to be.now only one of the textfields hold a value.

Comment: How are the pickers being used? Are both shown at all times or is each the `inputView` of each text field?

Comment: yes, they both need values each time the form used. One will have the current lender name and the second one will have a new lender. Both are populated from the same array.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: There are two pickers using the array lenders and there will be two more using a different array. So in total, there will be 4 on the form.

Comment: You still haven't answered my question. Let me try asking differently. Are all 4 pickers being shown on the screen at once and each one is tied to a specific text field or does tapping on a a text field cause a picker view to appear instead of a keyboard.

Comment: Yes, all four will display on the screen at the same time. when the user taps the text field the picker appears at the bottom of the screen.